# favicon not displaying in Shiny

Tags: shiny, favicon

I'd like to add a favicon to my shinymobile app and I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrect. The favicon works when i run the app locally however when i save to shinyapps.io. The code below shows my shiny app as well as the code for my manifest.json file. I have all of my images and favicon.io image saved in the www folder.

[image]

shiny app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)

ui <- f7Page(manifest = "manifest.json",
             favicon = "favicon.ico",
             icon = '128x128.png')
server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "short_name": "My App",
  "description": "My App",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "start_url": "https://7bdev.shinyapps.io/test_shiny/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not familiar with the `shinyMobile` package, but you can simply add it to the `head`

`tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico"))`

Comment: that was close, but i had to use the following code for it to work ```shiny::tags$link(rel = "icon", href = "icons/favicon.png")```